# How to get the list of amplitudes (volumes) from a video file as an array of floats in Swift

Tags: swift, audio, video, avfoundation, waveform

I need to get the list of amplitudes of a video file. The file is locally on the device. I just need the list of volumes by time as an array or dictionary. 
(Later I want to trim the video at the beginning and end where the volume is below a certain threshold, but this is not part of this question.)

So I need to read the video file, analyse the sound part and extract the volumes as an array or dictionary. I use Swift.

Here an image to demonstrate what I need the values for:
[image: Amplitudes of a video file]